# Highcharts Format tooltip for linkedTo: ':previous'

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have created a Stockchart with two data series, the second series has the attribute `linkedTo: ':previous'`

In the tooltip the name of the series appears two times (because the same series is added twice), I want to show the name only once.

Please see the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kami924/mg1cm7ye/6/)

I am trying to see the tooltip as:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `$.each(this.points, function(i, point) {` part you loop over the points for the tooltip.

One possible solution is to only add the `point.series.name` for the first point. And luckily you can check this with the `i` argument.

```
formatter: function() {
  var s = [];

  $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
    var content = '<span style="color:#D31B22;font-weight:bold;">'
    if (i === 0) {
      content += point.series.name + ': ';
    }

    content += point.y;
    content += '</span>';
    s.push(content);
  });

  return s.join(' and ');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mg1cm7ye/7/